# Memory/Performance issues with Fullscreen HTML kiosk app

Tags: javascript, html, performance, memory, fullscreen

I have to build a kiosk app which is essentially a bunch of fullscreen images with a few interactive pages, also fullscreen, in between, that should be swipeable.

Hardware environment is going to be mix of tablets and 32'' touch displays. The tablets will be handled by the guys standing at the exhibition booth, and the displays will be free to use for everyone. We're probably going to use Win 8 Pro Tablets and Windows PCs, which are connected to the touch displays.

This way I could build the app with `HTML/JS/CSS` running fullscreen in [Chrome's Kiosk Mode](http://think2loud.com/868-google-chrome-full-screen-kiosk-mode/). I was thinking about using [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/), which is great to combine image and html slides and works good with touch input.

The images are all going to have a resolution of 1920 x 1080, and there's going to be about 200 of them. Building a prototype I saw that this pushes `RoyalSlider` to the limits.

The problem is that I either leave `numImagesToPreload` at a small value which results in images not being ready instantly when swiping too fast or I set `numImagesToPreload` to a high value which ultimately makes the browser use a lot of memory and then crash as soon as I try swiping the first pages.

This is the prototype I've built

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="royalslider/royalslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="royalslider/skins/default/rs-default.css"> 

    <script src="royalslider/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="royalslider/jquery.royalslider.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html,body,div {
            margin:0; padding:0;
        }

        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow:hidden; // to avoid scrollbars
        }

        .royalSlider {
            position: absolute;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function processXML () {
            var xml = loadXML("data.xml");

            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
            var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

            $xml.find('page').each(function(index)
            {
                var src = $(this).find('src').text();
                var ext = src.split('.').pop();

                var newElement = 'None';

                if (ext === 'html') 
                {
                    newElement = loadHTMLFile(src);
                }
                else if (ext === 'jpg' || ext === 'jpeg' || ext === 'png') 
                {
                    newElement = '<img src="' + src + '" />';
                };

                $('.royalSlider').append(newElement);
            });
        }

        function loadHTMLFile (filename) {
            return loadFile(filename, 'html');
        }

        function loadXML (filename) {
            return loadFile(filename, 'xml');
        }

        function loadFile (filename, filetype) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: filename,
                dataType: filetype,
                async: false
                }).responseText;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            processXML();

            $(".royalSlider").royalSlider({
                controlNavigation: 'none',
                arrowsNav: false,
                navigateByClick: false,
                autoScaleSlider:false,
                autoHeight: false,
                imageScaleMode: 'none',
                slidesSpacing: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And a snippet of my `data.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
<page>
    <src>fullhd/page_001.jpg</src>
</page>
<page>
    <src>fullhd/page_002.jpg</src>
</page>
<page>
    <src>fullhd/page_003.jpg</src>
</page>
<page>
    <src>fullhd/page_004.jpg</src>
</page>
...
</content>
```

Does anybody know how I could optimize `RoyalSlider` to solve the problems above?
Or do you know any method/tool/framework that I should take a look at instead?

Comment: You may be in for a tricky time, since storing so many large images in-memory (as an uncompressed bitmap) is definitely going to take up space. Try using IE11's memory profiler, for starters. (Also; can you first be sure that the tablets you're planning on using have 1920x1080 screens, and not a pixel less?)

Comment: This might help - http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/slider-performance-tips

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with RoyalSlider, but it does list this as one of the features:

> **Memory management**
>
> Gallery keeps only a few slides in display list and doesn't use
>   "cloning" technque to save memory on mobile devices.

This is good; as you've noticed, loading every image into memory at the same time can go wrong.  Instead, you should just **leverage the browser cache**.

Your application and server need to allow the images to be cached; if not, change them so that they do.

Then the trick  is getting the images into the cache... .

Here is a jQuery solution that should automate getting each image into the cache (I haven't tested it).  It loads an image, removes it, then moves on to the next image:

```
var urls = ['img001.jpg', 'img002.jpg'],
    $image;

function loadImage(i) {

    if ($image) {
        // unload the image (but now its in the browser cache)
        $image.remove();
    }

    var url = urls[i];
    if (!url) {
        // no more images
        return;
    }

    $image = $('<img>', { src: urls[i], style: 'display: none' }).on('load', function () {
        // done loading this image; move to next one
        loadImage(i + 1);
    });

    // add the image to the DOM to make it load
    $(document.body).append($image);
}

loadImage(0);
```